# Excel - Combining multiple cells in a single row

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, microsoft-excel-2016

I have data disposed in this manner:

```
Jonh Seedman                New York, New York             01/01/1900
5th Ave                     +1 NXX-NXX-XXXX
Homer Simpson               Springfield, Illinois.         02/01/1900
742 Evergreen Terrace       +1 NXX-NXX-XXXX
Peter Parker                New York, New York             03/01/1900
20 Ingram St                +1 NXX-NXX-XXXX
```

I would like to hopefully get the following result using Excel (but not VBA):

```
    NAME.         BIRTH.             STATE.               ADDRESS.                    MOBILE
Jonh Seedman.   01/01/1900     New York, New York      5th Ave                   +1 NXX-NXX-XXXX
Homer Simpson   02/01/1900     Springfield, Illinois.  742 Evergreen Terrace     +1 NXX-NXX-XXXX
Peter Parker    03/01/1900     New York, New York      20 Ingram St              +1 NXX-NXX-XXXX
```

Any hints will be more than welcome guys. Thank you to whoever will take the time.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DaveWhite completely stuck on this point, spent the whole day cleaning this dataset

Comment: Is the data one row or two rows per person?

Comment: @harrymc two rows per person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your original data in `A:C`, enter the column headers in `F1:J1` and then the following formulas:

```
F2: =IF(INDEX($A:$A,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*2+1)="","",INDEX($A:$A,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*2+1))
G2: =IF(INDEX($C:$C,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*2+1)="","",INDEX($C:$C,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*2+1))
H2: =IF(INDEX($B:$B,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*2+1)="","",INDEX($B:$B,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*2+1))
I2: =IF(INDEX($A:$A,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*2+2)="","",INDEX($A:$A,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*2+2))
J2: =IF(INDEX($B:$B,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*2+2)="","",INDEX($B:$B,(ROWS($1:1)-1)*2+2))
```

*then fill down until you start seeing blanks*

***Source Data***
[image]

***Processed data***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that your data **always** falls in 3 columns and **always** spans 2 rows per record, then this would work...

1 - First create two helper columns.

```
Helper 1, alternate A & B on every other row. A formula can help you with this. 

Helper 2, number your data as it currently is... 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.
```

[image]

2 - Copy all your columns and paste in another sheet. Then order by Helper 1 and then Helper 2.

3 - Copy your Row "B" records and paste to the right of your row "A" records.

4 - Remove row B rows.

[image]

5 - Reorder your columns as you desire.